# Angular2 reading JSON

Tags: c#, json, http, angular, angular2-services

I have the following `GET` method for the `UsersController`

```
public IEnumerable<object> Get()
{
    var con = _context.Database.GetDbConnection();
    var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "sp_Users";
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Command", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = "GetUsers" });

    var retObject = new List<dynamic>();
    con.Open();
    using (var dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            var dataRow = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;
            for (var iFiled = 0; iFiled < dataReader.FieldCount; iFiled++)
                dataRow.Add(
                    dataReader.GetName(iFiled),
                    dataReader.IsDBNull(iFiled) ? null : dataReader[iFiled] // use null instead of {}
                );

            retObject.Add((ExpandoObject)dataRow);
        }
    }
    return retObject;
}
```

I tested it in `postman`and it worked perfectly returning:

```
[{"UserID": 1, "UserName": "foo"}, {"UserID": 2, "UserName": "bar"}]
```

Now I want to display them with `angular2`, so I coded a service `user.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
    student: any;
    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getUsers() {
        return this.http.get('api/users')
            .map((res: Response) => <string[]>res.json()); 
    }
}
```

And at `home.component.ts` I have:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.usersService.getUsers()
        .subscribe(users=> this.users = users);
    console.log(this.users);
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
core.umd.js:3462 EXCEPTION: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.umd.js:3462next @ core.umd.js:6924schedulerFn @ core.umd.js:6172SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.ts:238SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:190Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.ts:135Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:95Subject.next @ Subject.ts:61EventEmitter.emit @ core.umd.js:6164onError @ core.umd.js:6388onHandleError @ core.umd.js:6263ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:207Zone.runTask @ zone.js:139ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:304
core.umd.js:3467 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.umd.js:3467next @ core.umd.js:6924schedulerFn @ core.umd.js:6172SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.ts:238SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:190Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.ts:135Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:95Subject.next @ Subject.ts:61EventEmitter.emit @ core.umd.js:6164onError @ core.umd.js:6388onHandleError @ core.umd.js:6263ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:207Zone.runTask @ zone.js:139ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:304
core.umd.js:3468 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at Function.Json.parse (http.umd.js:188)
    at Response.Body.json (http.umd.js:1166)
    at MapSubscriber.eval [as project] (character.service.ts:11)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.ts:79)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:95)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.umd.js:1497)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:236)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.umd.js:6233)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:235)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:136)ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.umd.js:3468next @ core.umd.js:6924schedulerFn @ core.umd.js:6172SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.ts:238SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:190Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.ts:135Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:95Subject.next @ Subject.ts:61EventEmitter.emit @ core.umd.js:6164onError @ core.umd.js:6388onHandleError @ core.umd.js:6263ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:207Zone.runTask @ zone.js:139ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:304
Subscriber.ts:241 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Comment: `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` - your json ISN'T json. something else is there. `<` implies it's an html error or something.`<p>Warning:blahblalblah</p>{"json":"here"}` isn't valid json...

Comment: How can I debug it in angular? Because when I go to the application at `localhost:5000/api/users/` I get a text with JSON format and `postman` also shows me the same thing.

Comment: capture/output the raw returned data, before it gets to the json parser.

Comment: You should be able to use the network tab in the developer tools of whatever browser you're using to see the http request and response.  My guess is that the URL it's requesting isn't the right one - maybe an issue with your relative URL to the api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed with the following:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getUsers(): Observable<any[]> {
        return this.http.get('api/users')
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
        }
        private extractData(res: Response) {
            console.log(res);
            let body = res.json();
            return body.data || { };
        }
        private handleError (error: any) {
            // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
            // We'd also dig deeper into the error to get a better message
            let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
            error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
            console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
            return Observable.throw(errMsg);
        }
}
```